# Gitlab: execute script when job fails

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, cicd

I'd like to execute a script when a job fails.

In Gitlab you can define a job that runs when at least one job in an earlier stage fails: see Gitlab doc [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#when). I'd like to do something on a job-by-job basis instead.

There's a previous [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58428597/multiple-on-failure-events-for-each-job-in-gitlab) and [Gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/19400) that ask the same thing, but they don't suggest this solution using `after_script` and the [predefined variable](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) `CI_JOB_STATUS`:

```yaml
my-job:
  script:
    - ...
  after_script:
    - if [[ "${CI_JOB_STATUS}" == "failed" ]] ; then ./on_failure_script.sh ; fi
```

The point is that `after_script` is executed even if the job fails.  I guess one downside of this approach is that if something seriously goes wrong like the Gitlab runner crashes or something, maybe `after_script` won't get executed.

Any thoughts on this design?